# How to post data to ember route without showing in url?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Need to post data/datas to ember route without showing in url ,
Optional parameters  to route

Comment: are you talking about sending data to the route, with out using query paramters ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't specify the property as a query parameter you should be able to pass anything to the route and then on as a request without it showing in the Ember URL.